# How to logout the account without login into and logout Azure Portal again

Tags: azure, azureportal

I had logined into Azure portal with my company account which sets up  ADFS. Now, I want to use another account to login into Azure Portal. However, when I try to open `portal.azure.com` , it always redirect me to my company login page. I don't want to login agin and there is no section to switch account to my personal account.I can only use another accounts in my company. I hope I make sense about it.

**Question:** The login page is always redirected to my company login page. How do I get back  the orginal login page without loginning and logout again.(I know that It may work with clearing the broswer cache but I don't want this, I need some cache)

Comment: Which browser you're using? Is it IE or Edge?

Comment: @GauravMantri . I'm using Chrome .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to input this url in your broswer and Enter to go.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgraphexplorer.azurewebsites.net%2F
```

Then you will find that you can logout the orginal accounts. When you try to go to https://portal.azure.com, you can just use any account as you want :

[image]

I test this method in both Chrome and Edge, it works.

Answer (score 1):

For me personally, Firefox's [Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) solves this issue very well.

I can be logged in simultaneously to however many accounts I want and they are all neatly isolated.

The reason you run into this problem by the way is that this is a feature of Azure AD.
It's called Single Sign-On.
You sign in once, you are authenticated to all apps which use O365 auth.

Comment: Thanks for your explain. But I'm using Chrome.

Comment: It does not apply in your case then :) This answer might be useful for others who use Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways you can try.

1. Try to clear your browser cookie only on domain `login.microsoftonline.com`.
2. use `https://portal.azure.com/example.com` instead of `https://portal.azure.com`. `example.com` is your personal account domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! The second Method works fine, it also logs out first. But you need to specific one organization domain first.